# how to use a checkmark as a checkbox in css

Tags: html, css

I have a check mark as shown below, I want to use the check mark to act as a check box, I don't want the tick to appear inside a check box. I want to be able to click on the tick so it gets selected. It should be like a checkbox but with out the box, any suggestions if this can be done in css?

```css
.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkmark">
    <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
    <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Do some basic research please ... https://www.google.com/search?q=css+custom+checkbox

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Do you want it to look different when clicked, or what?

Comment: i want it to act as a check box

Comment: Could also do something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6yoz7d5/6/) if you want to play around with using javascript for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizing checkboxes is hard and requires a checkbox first.

You will need a checkbox to hold the value of the check. And you will need to style the label, and hide the checkbox, so that you will only see the label, and this label will be able to interact with the checkbox.

Try this instead :

```css
.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"] { display: none; }

.checkmark:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark:after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
<label for="cb" class="checkmark"></label>
```

Comment: No problem ! You can also find plenty of tutorials online for this type of question. I recommend you checking on CSS tricks, they publish very good articles !

Comment: thank you,will check up on that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean it?

```css
.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}

.checkbox-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox-hidden:checked + label .checkmark_stem, .checkbox-hidden:checked + label .checkmark_kick {
 background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-hidden" id="checkbox"> 
 <label class="checkmark" for="checkbox">
     <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
     <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
 </label>
```

Comment: You should provide a quick explanation of your snippet for beginners.